# How to send an email when a user responds to a comment

Tags: email, drupal, drupal-comments

What I want is to announce the original comment poster, when someone has responded on his comment
It's a bit blurry on how to do this with triggers.
Has anybody done that, or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly how to do it with the core Triggers module, but this can definitely be done with the [Rules Module](http://www.drupal.org/project/rules) (assuming Drupal 6... not sure of any issues with Drupal 7 version of Rules).

1. Download and install [Rules](http://www.drupal.org/project/rules)
2. Navigate to `admin/rules/trigger/add` to create a new rule, name it whatever you like and under the *Event* dropdown, choose "After saving a new comment" and click Save
3. Click on the "Add a condition" link choose "Execute custom PHP code".  In the PHP code area, add the following then click save:

   `if ($comment->pid != 0) {
     return TRUE;
   }
   else {
     return FALSE;
   }`
4. Click "Add an action" and choose "Load comment by id".  In the *Comment id* field add: `<?php echo $comment->pid; ?>` and click Save
5. Click "Add an action" again and choose "Load a user account". In the *User id* field add: `<?php echo $comment_loaded->uid; ?>` and click Save
6. Click "Add an action" again and choose "Send a mail to an arbitrary mail address".  In the *Recipient* field add: `<?php echo $user_loaded->mail; ?>` and fill in the other fields however you like to customize the email.

Now whenever a comment is replied to, an email will be sent to the "replied-to" comment author.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked perfectly fine for my requirement with couple of changes but still it helps me a lot. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 7 website 
Here is the code you can import under rules and update your subject and body as per your requirement:

```
{ "rules_send_reply_notice_for_comments" : {
"LABEL" : "Send reply notice for comments",
"PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
"OWNER" : "rules",
"TAGS" : [ "comments" ],
"REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "comment" ],
"ON" : { "comment_insert" : [] },
"IF" : [ { "NOT data_is_empty" : { "data" : [ "comment:parent" ] } } ],
"DO" : [
  { "mail" : {
      "to" : [ "comment:parent:mail" ],
      "subject" : "SUBJECT",
      "message" : "Here is the message you want to send [comment:body] regards Gaurav",
      "from" : "YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS",
      "language" : [ "" ]
    }
  }
]  } }
```